# SSL configurations in Rabbitmq.conf file is not being applied to my rabbitmq-server

Tags: ssl, openssl, rabbitmq

I installed rabbitmq on my aws EC2 machine with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Then I created the configuration file `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf` and added these parameters

```
listeners.ssl.1 = 5671
ssl_options.versions.1 = tlsv1.2
ssl_options.versions.2 = tlsv1.1
ssl_options.cacertfile           = /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/certifile_authority.crt
ssl_options.certfile             = /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/server.crt
ssl_options.keyfile              = /usr/local/share/private/server.key
ssl_options.verify               = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
```

**SIDENOTE**: I believe those `.crt` files are actually same format as `.pem` format (but I am not sure if I should rename them to .pem) because when I try to use the openssl command

`sudo openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in server.crt -out server.pem`

I get this message back

```
unable to load certificate
140162927387072:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1130:
140162927387072:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:290:Type=X509
```

Then I restarted the the server with `sudo service rabbitmq-server restart`
But after looking at all the logs in the `/var/log/rabbitmq` directory, I noticed that RabbitMQ is not even listening to the SSL port 5671. I am so confused and at a loss. Please help

- OS - ubuntu 18.04
- {ampq_client, "RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.6.10"}

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're using RabbitMQ `3.6.10`, which does *not* support configuration using the new `.conf`-format. You have two options:

- Upgrade to RabbitMQ 3.7.17 (the latest version)
- Configure RabbitMQ using the `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config` file, which is in Erlang term format ([docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#erlang-term-config-file), [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#enabling-tls)).

Note that RabbitMQ 3.6.X is no longer supported.

Comment: Oh man, I am so stupid. I even pasted the rabbitmq version too! Ok, so I guess this leads to my follow-up question: how come ubuntu did not install 3.7.X even after running `apt-get update`?

Comment: That is a Ubuntu packaging issue, I'm afraid. You should use one of our repositories - https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html